# Clearing previously uploaded file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using input type file in angularjs.

Here is the code

```
    <div class="fileUpload custom_upload btn custom_upload_btn">
    <input type="file" class="upload" custom-on-change="uploadFile"
    id="fileupload"/>
    </div>
```

Now I am able to upload file. But if I dont choose any file next time and then if I click submit then previously added file name it is taking. Can anyone tell how to clear out previously added file name so that next time if I add other data with no file then it should not add previously added file?

Here is my controller.js

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(event) {
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  var fileName = file.name;
  var fileSize = file.size;
  var ext = file.name.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
  $scope.isValid = false;
  var uploadUrl = "uploadFeeFiles";
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('file', file);

  $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': undefined
    }
  }).success(function(response) {
    $scope.defaultimage = false;
    $scope.feedocName = response;
  }).error(function(response) {});

  if (fileSize > 1000000) {
    $scope.isValid = true;
    $('#fileupload').val('');
  } else {
    $scope.isValid = true;
    $('#fileupload').val('');
  }
};
```

Comment: Java =/= javaScript

Comment: you should add check that if( FILE SELECTED ) then proceed else (THROW FILE NOT SELECTED ERROR)

Comment: post us more code about how u are uploading file ?

Comment: updated my question